# Searching value in multiple column

Tags: sql

Please help me to get this.

Input

```
Part_Number,Part_Type,Description_1,Value1, Description_2,Value2,Description_3 Value3

EDG38305,Gauge, Compatibility,CTS, Location,Dashboard,Head Light,DISC
```

i need output like this.

OUTPUT

```
Part_Number,Part_Type,Description_1,Value1, Description_2,Value2,Description_3 Value3

EDG38305,Gauge, '','', '','',Head Light,DISC
```

only value column which contain DISC with respective description that is if value 3 is DISC THEN OUTPUT SHOW DESCRIPTION 3 AND VALUE 3 AND REMAINING FEILD REMAIN BLANK

Thank You All

Comment: in mysql..? or what..?

Comment: @BREEN ho-  IN SQL SERVER 2008.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query

```
SELECT Part_Number,Part_Type,
      CASE WHEN  Value1 = 'DISC' THEN Description_1 ELSE '' END AS Description_1,
      CASE WHEN  Value1 = 'DISC' THEN Value1 ELSE '' END AS Value1,
      CASE WHEN  Value2 = 'DISC' THEN Description_2 ELSE '' END AS Description_2,
      CASE WHEN  Value2 = 'DISC' THEN Value2 ELSE '' END AS Value2,
      CASE WHEN  Value3 = 'DISC' THEN Description_3 ELSE '' END AS Description_3,
      CASE WHEN  Value3 = 'DISC' THEN Value3 ELSE '' END AS Value3
```

You have to change the IN clause according to the required number of static values that you want to check

Comment: Here, Value1, Value2, Value3 are always 'Disc'. is'nt it..??

Comment: No Breen, value 1, value2,value3 may contain multiple value where DISC is one of them.

Comment: @user3751360. I think you need to then change the query as above

Comment: @KiranHegde., Now, the edited answer seems good..!! But, I dont understand what is 'DESC2' ..? Is it simply a rough value to make sure DESC is available as value..??

Comment: @Breenho. According to the above comment, he wants to check if value contains DISC, or other values(DISC2 in this case), then return description and value, otherwise '' for both.

Comment: value 1, description 1,value2, description2,value3, description3 are column name, and in any of the value column (value1 or value2 or value3) contain DISC i need to have the output Disc present in value column with description , that means if value 2 contain "DISC" THEN OUTPUT contain Value 2 with the data in description2. similarly if value 3 contain "DISC", then output contain Data in value3 and data in description3.